# ng-repeat not comparing values on ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have an array of elements, $scope.hides = [3,5] and i am comparing these values with values in a table using ng-repeat and ng-if..

If a value in array and table matches, that row in the table should be hided,

[image]

The array elements are - 3,5 and table values come after ||. 
     [3,5] (array value) || 1 (table value).

Since there are 2 elements, the ng-repeat iterates 2 times and removing one element in each iteration. I want to remove all matching elements in single iteration

Here is my code,

```
ng-repeat="x in hides track by $index"  ng-if="x != (values populated from controllers)"
```

Can anyone help to remove all matching elements in single iteration than 2 iterations...

Comment: what is `(values populated from controllers)`?  is it an array?

Comment: yeah thats an array too @plong0

Comment: is it in the div or span ? or ?

Comment: its in table within <tr> tag...

Comment: Seems you are trying to compare two objects than string, which will never be same.

Answer (score 0):

Since `(values populated from controllers)` is an array and `x` is an integer, you will need to check that `x` *does not exist in* `(values populated from controllers)`

The simplest way for a flat array of primitives is like so:

`ng-if="(values populated from controllers).indexOf(x) == -1"`

If you need more advanced lookup to see if x exists in the array, you might consider ditching the ng-if and using something like:  `ng-repeat="x in hides track by $index | filter:isInArray` where `$scope.isInArray` is a custom predicate function that as per the [filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).